# How to show that the following function is not a OWF?

Tags: one-way-function, pseudo-random-permutation

Given F, which is a Pseudo Random Permutation, I need to prove that the following function f is not a OWF:

f(x, y) = F<sub>x</sub>(y)

My first thought would be to create an adversary which tries and compute F<sub>x</sub><sup>-1</sup>(y) with different values for x, but I'm not sure it would be PPT. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you truncate the permutation then it cannot be inverted.

Answer (score 1):

Any $x$ is fine. Since $F$ is a PRP, for any key $x$ and output string $z$ there is an input string $y$ such that $F_x(y) = z$.